# Adding CSRF value for codeigniter in Jquery file upload

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, csrf, jquery-file-upload

I am using blueimp jquery file upload and I am having a issue when CSRF protection is set to true. I manage to send all the other ajax request properly but this one does not work. The return value is unknown.

I have tried to set CSRF as header or sending it with form data but nothing works.

Please help.

Comment: Can you show your code and what you have tried?

Comment: The CSRF needs to be included in the post fields, the name of it is defined in your config. Need to see your code to be able to help you. Could just be tossing a `form_open()` in the view, or feeding it through with the loader class, too hard to say with what you gave.

Comment: Hey, I figured it out, I was using custom html form, I changed it to `form_open` and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Same issues occur with me, but I solved this by addding csrf token in posting url while using ajax. 
I hope this code sample may help you:

```
$('.cust_active').live('click', function () {
    var cct = $("input[name=csrf_test_name]").val();//alert(cct);
    id = $(this).attr("id").val();
    $.post(site_url + "admin/product_ban_status", { id: id[0], status:1 , 'csrf_test_name': cct})
    .done(function(data) {
        // code for result
        }); 

});`
```

Also for csrf you need to use form_open() and form_close() function of codeigniter in each form.